# In which function to load tableView data when the data comes from remote API

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController instance, which is the data source and the delegate.

The data is provided by a remote API, that takes some time to be  called.

I know how to call and populate the cells for sure, but i don't know in which function i need to call the API that loads the data.

Typically i will have something like

```
var myData : [myOption]?
```

and when i populate the cells, i can ask if that array is nil or not and if not i can call the API, **is this a good way?**

Comment: Normally you would initiate the load in `viewDidLoad` and then refresh the table once the load has completed.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'll give it a shot thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically you're going to want to keep your data out of the view controller, and you absolutely want to keep your API calls out of the view controller. Create a "model" object that talks to the API. The simplest way to do this is to make the model a [shared singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html). (There are some reasons not to use singletons here, but if you're new, I would absolutely do it this way.)

Again, to keep things simple, I recommend using `NSNotification` to let the model announce when data has changed. The view controller will observe this notification, and when it is posted, it'll call `reloadData` to refresh itself. All of the data source methods (`numberOfRowsInSection`, etc.) will be simple calls to the model.

This is the traditional way to build Cocoa apps, and the way I highly recommend people start. As you learn more, you'll probably find other tools that can be better than `NSNotification`, and you can learn other patterns that replace singletons. And you'll *definitely* learn better ways to update your table than `reloadData`, but this will get you a good, strong foundation to improve on.

One of the better pieces of example code, IMO, that demonstrates all of this is [The Elements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html). I highly recommend studying it. It's in ObjC, but it's very clearly written, and learning to convert ObjC to Swift is a core competency of Cocoa developers. (The Elements doesn't talk to a server, but it demonstrates the Model View Controller pattern that you need.)